# How to reverse the pagination numbers of an archive?

Tags: themes, pagination, archives

I have archive pages that each contain titles and excerpts from 10 blog entries. Both entries and archive pages are in **reverse chronological order**:

- when a new blog entry is written its title and excerpt go to the top of the front page;
- when you are on one page and you click through to "Next page", you get the titles and excerpts for the 10 previous blog entries.

This is pretty standard for blogs.

But the archive pages are **numbered** by default in the same order. Thus Page 1 contains excerpts from the most recent 10 entries, Page 2 contains excerpts from the next 10 most recent, etc.

To be clear: at the moment, "Next page" refers to the page with the next higher number. Thus the front page, which contains excerpts from the most recent entry and the nine next most recent entries, is labelled Page 1, and the 10 entries posted before those 10 entries are on Page 2.

**I need the page-numbering the other way round, namely in direct chronological order**, so that for example if there are 97 entries then

- entries 28-37 would be excerpted on Page 4, and
- the PREVIOUS page from there, containing excerpts from entries 18-27, would be called page 3.

How can I achieve this, whether by amending functions.php in the child theme (preferably), by writing a "Snippet" (next most preferred), or by amending archive.php in the Astra parent theme directly (least preferred, because of possible update problems)?

**Edit**

The following isn't a solution but it may be part of one. This re-numbers pages into direct chronological order, but unfortunately it also reverses the order in which they are shown (from reverse chronological to direct chronological). So it causes the front archive paget to contain excerpts from the earliest posts rather than the latest ones!

```php
<?php

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_by_forward_date');

function posts_by_forward_date($query) {
  if(is_archive() || is_home()) {
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should be able to do this "amending archive.php in the Astra parent theme" but instead create a copy of the file and then add it to your child theme where you're free to make edits as needed.  You may need to periodically check the Astra updates/changelogs to see if they modified that file so you can address anything you yourself may need to update. (This is the third time today someone's asked about this theme... ...is this the new Avada?)

Comment: Thanks, @TonyDjukic, but what should I actually write in functions.php or whatever the appropriate file in the parent theme is? I've got as far as being able to number the posts forward in time (as described in the edit), but something is still showing them in *numerically indexed order* on the archive page, which kinda defeats the purpose. I want them in backwards chronological order (i.e. newest first) and also backwards numerical order (just as the current issue of a periodical will have a higher number than a previous issue).

Comment: Unless someone on here is really familiar with the Astra theme and it's templates it's going to be really difficult for anyone to actually answer.  You can try posting the archive.php code here and see if someone can help address that.

Comment: I can do that if you like, but that file has a lot of dependencies.

Comment: What you want is how WP already orders archives by default. Posts are shown with the newest first, and the oldest last. If this is not the case on your archive page, then your theme or a plugin has meddled in the query to change the order, or, it has replaced the query with its own. Without seeing the code, it's impossible for any of us to know. Additionally, **3rd party theme dev support is off topic here and not in the scope of this stack**, you need to contact Astra theme support, or ask in communities of Astra theme users

Comment: I've reopened the question, and made some edits, in particular the title. It read as a textbook theme help question, that you actually wanted to change how pagination numbers work was difficult to prise out. It still needs modifications as it's not easy to understand but i've done what i can to make the question clearer, and there's still some ambiguity. E.g. do you mean you want the numbers to appear  10, 9 ,8 ,7 ,6... **1**? Or do you mean if you have 20 pages, that visiting the archive jumps straight to page 20?

Comment: Thanks Tom. And apologies for my lack of clarity. I have further tweaked your edit. I hope this is sufficiently comprehensible now.

Comment: To answer your questions: I want it to continue to jump to the newest page, but I want that page to be called Page 20. ("Page 20" would be a bit like "Issue 20" of a magazine, although I didn't say that in the question for fear of causing even more confusion.)